# OpenGL ES Multithreading

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Recently I started working with OpenGL ES. But I encountered problematic multithreading. All my attempts to transfer new vertices in any way failed. My classes are lower.

**MainActivity:**

```
package danielbernar.opengl.test;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.opengl.*;
import danielbernar.opengl.test.OpenGLTools.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    OpenGLRenderer oglr;
    public static Scene0 sc0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sc0 = new Scene0();

        oglr = new OpenGLRenderer(MainActivity.this);
        glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(MainActivity.this);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2); 
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(oglr);
        glSurfaceView.setRenderMode(glSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
        setContentView(glSurfaceView);

        glSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1) {
                    sc0.bgcolor = new float[]{1, 1, 1, 1};
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**Scene0:**

```
package danielbernar.opengl.test;
import java.nio.*;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.*;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer;
import danielbernar.opengl.test.OpenGLTools.*;
import android.opengl.*;

public class Scene0
{
    public float[] bgcolor = {0, 0, 0, 1};

    public void drawTrng(int aPositionLocation, int uColorLocation) {
        float[] v = {
            0, 0, -1,
            100, 100, -1,
            100, 0, -1
        };
        FloatBuffer f = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(v.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        f.put(v);
        GLES20.glClearColor(bgcolor[0], bgcolor[1], bgcolor[2], bgcolor[3]); // OK
        GLES20.glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, f); 
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // NOT WORK
    }

}
```

**OpenGLRenderer:**

```
package danielbernar.opengl.test.OpenGLTools;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_FLOAT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_POINTS;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glDrawArrays;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glGetAttribLocation;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glGetUniformLocation;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUniform4f;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUseProgram;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glEnable;
import android.*;
import android.opengl.*;
import java.util.*;
import danielbernar.opengl.test.*;

public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer {
    private Context context;
    private int programId;
    private FloatBuffer vertexData;
    private int uColorLocation;
    private int uMatrixLocation;
    private int aPositionLocation;
    //String vertex_shader = "attribute vec4 a_Position; void main() { gl_Position = a_Position; gl_PointSize = 5.0; }"; // 2D
    String vertex_shader = "attribute vec4 a_Position; uniform mat4 u_Matrix; void main() { gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position; gl_PointSize = 1.0; }"; // 3D
    String fragment_shader = "precision mediump float; uniform vec4 u_Color; void main() { gl_FragColor = u_Color; }";

    static final int GL_COORDINATES_COUNT = 3; // XYZ

    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] vertices = new float[0];

    public static final int GL_TRIANGLE = GL_TRIANGLES;

    public OpenGLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        prepareData();
        System.out.println("OpenGL created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
        arg0.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        int vertexShaderId = ShaderUtils.createShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader);
        int fragmentShaderId = ShaderUtils.createShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment_shader);
        programId = ShaderUtils.createProgram(vertexShaderId, fragmentShaderId);
        glUseProgram(programId);
        bindData();
        System.out.println("OpenGL surfaceCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        bindMatrix(width, height);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": OpenGL onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height)");
    }

    public void addTrng(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2, float x3, float y3, float z3) {
        float[] tmpVert = new float[vertices.length + 3*3]; // 3v and 3c
        System.arraycopy(vertices, 0, tmpVert, 0, vertices.length);
        int verl = vertices.length;
        tmpVert[verl] = x1;
        tmpVert[verl+1] = y1;
        tmpVert[verl+2] = z1;
        tmpVert[verl+3] = x2;
        tmpVert[verl+4] = y2;
        tmpVert[verl+5] = z2;
        tmpVert[verl+6] = x3;
        tmpVert[verl+7] = y3;
        tmpVert[verl+8] = z3;
        vertices = tmpVert;
    }
    public void addRect(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2) {
        addTrng(x1, y1, z1, x1, y2, z1, x2, y2, z2);
        addTrng(x1, y1, z1, x2, y1, z2, x2, y2, z2);
    }

    public void draw() {
        prepareData();
    }

    private void prepareData() {
        vertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        vertexData.put(vertices);
    }

    public void setVertices(float[] vertices) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        prepareData();
    }

    public void setFloatBuffer(FloatBuffer vertexData) {
        this.vertexData = vertexData;
    }

    private void bindData() {
        uColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "u_Color");
        aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_Position");
        vertexData.position(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, GL_COORDINATES_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexData);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

        // matrix
        uMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "u_Matrix");
    }

    private void bindMatrix(int width, int height) {
        float left = 0;
        float right = width;
        float bottom = height;
        float top = 0;
        float near = 1.0f;
        float far = 8.0f;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, mProjectionMatrix, 0);
    }

    private void draw0() {
        MainActivity.sc0.drawTrng(aPositionLocation, uColorLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUniform4f(uColorLocation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        draw0();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors or vertex buffer is just empty?

Comment: I checked, and the vertex buffer isnt empty. If the same code is run in onDrawFrame, then everything will work.

Comment: So which part of the code exactly you ran in onDrawFrame for everything to work? Also, try checking if there are any GL errors. And one more question - where is the code that calls any methods that actually change `vertices[]` ( `setVertices()`, `addRect()` )?

Comment: What with these methods that without - without result. I did them for convenient work with OpenGL.

Comment: I found the problem, the problem was in the absence of this line: `f.position (0);`